# How can I check if the 'Allow Full Access' toggle in app settings (for a keyboard extension) is enabled from within the container app?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Working on an iOS Swift keyboard extension app, and I'm facing an issue.
In the **container app** code (not within the extension app itself), I need to determine whether the user has granted **'Allow Full Access'** permission for the keyboard extension.

I've searched extensively on Google and StackOverflow, but I couldn't find a viable solution. However, I noticed that the [**Wordtune**](https://wordtune.com) iOS app seems to have figured out a workaround.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation or knows how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you use an app group to share some data between your keyboard extension and your main app?

Comment: Nope, In keyboard extension you can only read shared data (when allow full access is off) and not writing new one (between the container app and the keyboard extension).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if "Allow Full Access" permission is granted from containing app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32119938/how-to-test-if-allow-full-access-permission-is-granted-from-containing-app)

Comment: Unfortunately, its only half of the answer. Again, I want to be able to know if the keyboard got "Allow for access" without forcing the user to open the keyboard first.
the hack exists for sure since we can see example of it on the Wordtune app.